# Have to unplug and plug the USB speaker to work after sleep

Tags: usb, 22.04, suspend

When I plug this USB speaker it works fine. It will also be listed as below when I run `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 043: ID 1908:2070 GEMBIRD Honk HK-5002 USB Speaker
```

But when the system goes to sleep or suspend the device is no longer available. `lsusb` doesn't list it either. Even tried `sudo usbreset 1908:2070` which fails with this error: `No such device found`.

I guess one way is to disable USB autosuspend but I wonder if there's any better way?

OS: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS